# Facebook Login Error SDK 3.0

Tags: android, ios, facebook

Anybody faced such kind of issue. I guess, this is specific to device. I'm using Facebook sdk-3.0 android. When i press back home button, it takes me to browser and i puts my credentials in but still it showing me this error for android. While in ios i still face this error window but pressing back home and logging in facebook to browser, my ios application works fine.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> back home button

Back and Home are two separate buttons on Android, could you provide some code ?

What tablet model are you using ?

Also try to change / set *targetSdkVersion* ( in AndroidManifest.xml ) to Android 4.x API level 15-17

Comment: I'm using sony tablet S model. I tried to set targetSDKVersion in android manifest but no benefit.

Comment: I was recently working with Facebook SDK 3.0 it requires some code but it is not that complex, I didn't encountered that kind of issue.

If you need help it would be great to see some code in other case there isn't much to tell about this. Also it is quite impossible to go back to Facebook login dialog since it is opened in another activity which is closed after login and removed from the backstack.

Comment: Yeah, I've configured facebook code fine and its working for other device. One thing happend here, as i faced this issue on two devices, i factory reset one device and don't this issue on that any more. This is related to device. I guess some other app using facebook probleming with this. Still looking into it. Thanks!